# SQL Server : insert a new row as ID of 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `ComplaintCodes` which contains about 15 rows and 2 columns: `ComplaintCodeId` and `ComplaintCodeText`.

I want to insert a new row into that table but have its ID set to 1 which will also add 1 to all of the ID's that exist already. Is this possible?

### EDIT

Using SQL Server and `ComplaintCodeId` is an identity / PK column

Comment: Depends on the variety of SQL that you are using.

Comment: Is ComplaintCodeId a foreign key?

Comment: Will the ID values be sequential starting at 1 or will their be a gap? I don't know what you started the seed value off as. But you should really consider your design, if you are relying on the PK for a display order, you are doing it wrong. Add a DisplayOrder column and order off that value.

Comment: If `ID` is an `IDENTITY` column, you cannot do this. You can *insert* specific values for the `ID` column into a new row, but you **cannot** change/update (add +1) to existing identity column's values.

Comment: @marc_s - I was thinking that it would be possible if the values were sequential and there was not relationships to script a select current data to a temp table, truncate the table, insert the record, and re-insert the old values. Hackish at best

Comment: @marc_s - It wouldn't be a true update (UPDATE DML). But truncating would reseed the identity column, so he would get the same end result

Comment: @SpectralGhost: true - that would most likely work - but I agree: hackish at best...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update <table> set ComplaintCodeId =ComplaintCodeId +1

insert into <table>
select 1,'other column'
```

**Edit**:

If its a PK+Identity column, then its a very bad idea to do like this. You cannot update an identity column..

Instead of updating you could do something like this:

```
select row_number() over (order by ComplaintCodeId desc) as row_num,
       ComplaintCodeId 
from table
```

and use row_num instead of ComplaintCodeId

Answer (score 5):

It's possible as two separate DML statements, an UPDATE to update the ID and a subsequent INSERT. But this will fail if you are using the ID as a foreign key in another table of course, so you'd need to find a way to update across all related tables.

Why would you want to do this though? Suggest you take a step back and reconsider the design decision that has brought you to this question.

And yes, as podiluska says in his/her(/its!) comment, please specify which DBMS you are using in your question and/or tags.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, it seems to me that the best solution to your problem is to change the PK to be non-identity. Then you can set the value to whatever you'd like.

I still think that using a Display Order column (which is the only reason I can think you'd care the order in the table) would be a fine solution, but if you really want the PK order to be the display order, then changing the PK to non-identity would be a good long-term solution as you wouldn't have these problems in the future.